# Get order list filtered by greater than by specific order id in Prestashop rest API

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I am newer in Prestashop,

I need to get the order list in which orders should be greater than a specific order_id using Rest API. Let suppose there are 100 orders and I need to fetch all the orders greater than 45(order_id). How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by composing the URL like that :

```
http://localhost/api/orders?filter[id]=>[45]
```